# Correct way to validate zip inner files in nestjs app

Tags: nestjs, zip

I have a simple webapp with React and Nestjs.
I want to upload a zip file from the UI, through nest, and then to something like S3.
But, first I want to validate the contents of the zip file, and for example upload to S3 only "valid" (I will define it. let's say pdf, csv etc.) files, and filter out not valid files (.exe etc.).
How can I do it? just unzip and iterate through the files?
I want to do it for security reasons, so I prefer not to extract the zip in the backend..
should I do it on frontend? any other solution?